# Is there any way to rotate images in Trello?

Tags: trello, trello-cards, image-manipulation

[image: Uuuuughly!]

I am constantly adding images to Trello cards to serve as their cover photos as well as to document things (Yay, I love visualizations!)

Out of habit, and sometimes because of the desired photo aspect ratio, I take pictures in portrait mode on my phone. Most modern desktop and mobile apps have no difficulty recognizing and orienting the photos properly, so I don't notice they need to be rotated 90 degrees until it's too late.

When I upload them to Trello however these photos are displayed horizontally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Currently (7/27/2018) there is no way to rotate images in Trello, either in the Electron app or in the Android app...